# Why does "DEFAULT" is causing syntax problem

Tags: sql-server

I'm new in using SQL Server and right now I'm trying to change "Id" column from default ID to GUID.
When using this code

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Bookings ALTER COLUMN Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID();
```

It gets me an error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'DEFAULT'
```

And I don't understand where is the syntax problem.
Can anyone point it out what is causing this error?

Comment: there is no UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  at mysql

Comment: Let's see the current table structure. Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE dbo.Bookings;` and [post the result in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69750832/edit). Also please check your MySQL version by running this query `SELECT version();`

Comment: i suspect its sqlserver

Comment: This looks like SQL Server syntax rather than [`MySQL`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info). Have you tagged the question correctly? If it is [`SQL Server`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info), I don't think you can alter the type and add a default in the same statement. You'd need to do it in two separate statements. e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ee02014eb5f0857c46f86f6fccdfe5e

Comment: @GarethD Sorry, I really messed it up. It's SQL Server, you are right.

Comment: This is an interesting use case to me. Specifically, what is the current data type for the column?

Comment: @BenThul current datatype is INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the add constraint syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Bookings ADD CONSTRAINT DF_dbo_Bookings_Id DEFAULT(NEWID()) FOR Id;
```

Also, if your table have the primary key clustered on that Id column, you could use the NEWSEQUENTIALID for creating unique identifiers that will have less impact on your writes:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Bookings ADD CONSTRAINT DF_dbo_Bookings_Id DEFAULT(NEWSEQUENTIALID()) FOR Id;
```

[Example, on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=faf13f64f452e36769fc03564870eb7b)

Comment: Now I'm not getting any syntax errors, but it shows me other error:
`Msg 1754, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Defaults cannot be created on columns with an IDENTITY attribute. Table 'Bookings', column 'Id' `

Comment: I solved this problem by recreating a database and your code works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Bookings
ALTER COLUMN id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Bookings
ALTER id SET DEFAULT  NEWID();
```

Its possible using the alters separately.

Its the best to backup current table to avoid potential data loss.